# KnockoutJS: Select object as return value

Tags: select, knockout.js, binding

I am trying to convert an existing template from button clicks to a select with options. The original template looks like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: amounts, as: 'amount'} -->
<button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.changeAmount.bind($parent)">
    <span data-bind="text: amount.amountFormatted"></span>
</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The content of the array `amounts` is this:

```
[

    {
        "baseValue":"15",
        "value":15,
        "amountFormatted":"15,00 €",
        "price":"15,00 €"
    },
    {
        "baseValue":"25",
        "value":25,
        "amountFormatted":"25,00 €",
        "price":"25,00 €"
    },
    {
        "baseValue":"50",
        "value":50,
        "amountFormatted":"50,00 €",
        "price":"50,00 €"
    }
]
```

And this is the handler function:

```
changeAmount: function (amount) {
    console.log(amount);
    this.activeAmount(amount);
}
```

The `console.log` shows me how the return value of the button click looks like:

```
{
    "baseValue":"50",
    "value":50,
    "amountFormatted":"50,00 €",
    "price":"50,00 €"
}
```

Now I want this whole thing displayed as a select instead of buttons:

```
<select data-bind="options: amounts,
   optionsText: 'amountFormatted',
   optionsValue: 'value',
   value: activeAmount,
   event:{ change: changeAmount}"></select>
```

But with this template the select returns the entire view object instead of what a button click returns. How can I get the select to return the same object/array?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be needing this as the minimal working sample:

1. The amounts observableArray with the options
2. The binding below:

> ```
> <select data-bind="options: amounts,
>    optionsText: 'amountFormatted',
>    value: activeAmount"></select>
> ```

You are also using the event binding which is probably not needed on your context at all, you are binding it against the parent but instead of working with `this` you are also expecting the amount to be passed in, which does not work well with your click handler definition ( where you bind the function, ok, but no params are given if you go through that route ).

Rework your context and the click handler, so that it accesses `activeAmount` such that you dont expect a parameter. Since you are bound on the parent, just use this.activeAmount internally.

Note: you dont need to do anything to update the `activeAmount` if the select bind works properly. it will contain the seleced option's formattedAmount text already